# Want to get a result like below. how to write a query for that

Tags: php

```
{"result": [
        {
            "room_id": "1",
            "floor_id": "1",
            "flat_id": "1",
            "room_name": "Room1",
            "no_of_cots": "4",
            "cot_info":[{"cot_id": "1",
            "cot_name": "COT1",
            "cot_status": "1"},
            {"cot_id": "2",
            "cot_name": "COT2",
            "cot_status": "1"}],
            "flat_name": "Sumangali PG",
            "floor_name": "GroundFloor"
        },
        {
            "room_id": "2",
            "floor_id": "1",
            "flat_id": "1",
            "room_name": "Room2",
            "no_of_cots": "2",
            "cot_info":[{"cot_id": "1",
            "cot_name": "COT1",
            "cot_status": "1"},
            {"cot_id": "2",
            "cot_name": "COT2",
            "cot_status": "1"}],
            "flat_name": "Sumangali PG",
            "floor_name": "GroundFloor"
        } ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and at what point are you stuck in what you've tried ?

Comment: Open IDE and write a query. That's all what can be advised for such a question.

Comment: Need more info, like are you quering from a database, do you want the SQL Query or just how to form that json string

Comment: I want SQL query.. want to fetch data from four tables, have a foreign key

Comment: This is not how SO works, we don't *do* it for you, we provide help to solve a specific problem you're facing when trying your own solution. Put some effort and we definitly will too. Try something, show what you've tried, where and why you're stuck and we'll be pleased to help.

Comment: SELECT t1.room_id, t1.floor_id, t1.flat_id, t1.room_name, t1.no_of_cots, t2.flat_name, t3.floor_name, t4.cot_id, t4.cot_name, t4.cot_status
 FROM room_details as t1 
 JOIN flat_details as t2 ON t1.flat_id = t2.flat_id
 JOIN floor_details as t3 ON t1.floor_id = t3.floor_id
 JOIN cot_details as t4 ON t1.flat_id = t4.flat_id
where t1.apartment_id='$apartment_id     , I wrote like this, it gives a list not an array of array.

Comment: How to write a query to get a result as array of array?  - nohow. Make it by php

Answer (score 0):

OK you can use two page one for proccess the query example 
should be like that then you can addit to an array then decode the array and make echo like in the example bellew:

```
//page source
$query ='select room_id,floor_id,flat_id,room_name,no_of_cots,cot_info,cot_id,cot_name,cot_status,flat_name,floor_name 
from table1 ,table2,table3,table4 where  table1.id=table2.id and table2.id=table3.id and table4.id=table3.id';

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  $array_list=array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  $array_list['room_id']=$row;
  $array_list['floor_id']=$row;
  $array_list['flat_id']=$row;
  $array_list['room_name']=$row;
  $array_list['cot_info']=$row;
  $array_list['cot_name']=$row;
  $array_list['cot_id']=$row;
  $array_list['cot_status']=$row;
  $array_list['flat_name']=$row;
  $array_list['floor_name']=$row;

    }


      $json_data = array(
                            "result"            => $array_list,
                            );
                            echo json_encode($json_data);



// page 2   
$content='{"result": [ { "room_id": "1", "floor_id": "1", "flat_id": "1", "room_name": "Room1", "no_of_cots": "4", "cot_info":[{"cot_id": "1", "cot_name": "COT1", "cot_status": "1"}, {"cot_id": "2", "cot_name": "COT2", "cot_status": "1"}], "flat_name": "Sumangali PG", "floor_name": "GroundFloor" }, { "room_id": "2", "floor_id": "1", "flat_id": "1", "room_name": "Room2", "no_of_cots": "2", "cot_info":[{"cot_id": "1", "cot_name": "COT1", "cot_status": "1"}, {"cot_id": "2", "cot_name": "COT2", "cot_status": "1"}], "flat_name": "Sumangali PG", "floor_name": "GroundFloor" } ] }';



$json=json_decode($content);

foreach($json->result as $row)
{
    print_r($row);



}
```